# jQuery append image to div not showing but can see it on Firebug

Tags: jquery, imagemagick, firebug, jquery-append

I have this design application which allows users to dynamically add text(append) on a div using jQuery. The text is generated using ImageMagick(so it has some effects like curve,wave, etc..) and it is in png format.

My problem is that whenever I try to process the image and jQuery-append it to the html div "sometimes" it wont show up, but when checking with firebug I can see that the element/image is there. I'm guessing this is about "delay" in internet connection while generating image.

Is there a way to "preload" or make sure that the image is created before it is appended to the div ?

The image is created via jQuery post to a "php" file with "shell_exec("imagemagick command")" and I've already added a callback when the post is finished(the append happens here).

Thanks (",)

Comment: Can you show us the code you're trying to use?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".appender").click(function() {
   $(".appendingDiv").append($('<img />').attr('src', 'http://imagesrc.com'));
})
```